# Gravaty Forms Conditional Logic Redirect

Tags: plugins

0
down vote
favorite
I am working on a gravity form and

at the end of the form, i want the user to have the option to choose between 2 social media sites to submit their review.

Example:

"It was our pleasure to serve you. Would you take a few minutes to help others in the community by sharing your experience at one of the following sites?"

Yes... No...

if they choose yes they must get the option to choose between google or facebook. there is an option in the form itself to redirect the user to an url but i cannot find a way to make the user choose one of the 2 social media sites before they get redirected to the ones they have chosen.

i also don't see a conditional logic redirect option.

any ideas how i can accomplish this?

Comment: are you using confirmation redirect?